# Lua optimize memory

Tags: performance, memory, optimization, lua

I what to optimize my code. I have 3 option don't know which is better for memory in Lua:

1)

```
local Test = {}
    Test.var1 = function ()
        -- Code
    end

    Test.var2 = function ()
        -- Code
    end
```

2) Or

```
function var1()
    -- Code
end

function var2()
    -- Code
end
```

3) Or maybe

```
local var1 = function ()
    -- Code
end

local var2 = function ()
    -- Code
end
```

Comment: Third is better than second I think, but not sure

Comment: what do you want to [optimize here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)? If you want object-oriented-like structure, use the first, if you want to add globals, accessible from anywhere, use the second (2 functions are not expensive), if you want functions visible in your local scope, use the third option.

Comment: How is that related to optimizing *memory*?

Comment: Adding to what @YuHao already told you in his answer, always remember to put your primary effort into making the program: 1.correct, 2.readable (by humans!). In this world of quad-cores, super-optimizing compilers and OSes with lots of frills memory/speed optimizations are rarely a concern, unless you hit very specific problems, but in this cases **you need to be an expert** (or you need to hire one). Of course if you are just learning Lua it is good to know some implementation details affecting performance/mem-footprints, but "I want to optimize my code" is usually a big no-no for a beginner.

Comment: I am limited in resources of memory, periodically I get Crashes. I doesn't want use optimization because it good. I need it!

Comment: Are you using eLua? Otherwise in modern computer systems none of these options will have much effect on memory usage (unless you have a few million functions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [Lua Programming Gem](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf), the two maxims of program optimization:

- Rule #1: Don’t do it.
- Rule #2: Don’t do it yet. (for experts only)

Back to your examples, the second piece of code is a little bit worse as the access to global ones is slower. But the performance difference is hardly noticeable.

It depends on your needs, the first one uses an extra table than the third one, but the namespace is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

None will really affect memory, barring the use of a table in #1 (so some 40 bytes + some per entry).

If its performance you want, then option #3 is far better, assuming you can access said functions at the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about memory usage more than processing and you're using object-oriented programming where you're instantiating multiple instances of `Test` as you showed above, you have a fourth option with metatables.

```
TestMt = {}
TestMt.func1 = function(self, ...)
    ...
end
TestMt.func2 = function(self, ...)
    ...
end
TestMt.func3 = function(self, ...)
    ...
end

function new_test()
    local t = {}
    t.data = ...
    setmetatable(t, {__index = TestMt})
    return t
end

foo = new_test()
foo:func1()
foo:func2()
foo:func3()
```

If you're doing object-oriented kind of programming, metatables can lead to a massive savings in memory (I accidentally used over 1 gigabyte once for numerous mathematical vectors this way, only to reduce it down to 40 megabytes by using the metatable).

If it's not about objects and tables that get instantiated many times, and just about organizing your globally-accessible functions, worrying about memory here is ridiculous. It's like putting the entirety of your lua code into one file in order to reduce file system overhead. You're talking about such negligible savings that you should really need an extraordinary use case backed by meticulous measurements to even concern yourself with that.

If it's about processing, then you can get some small improvements by keeping your global functions out of nested tables, and by favoring locals when possible.